# Django Admin - display image on hover

Tags: javascript, css, django, django-admin

I'd like to display a thumbnail in a popover when I hover over text (a camera emoji) in our Django Admin view. The code I have works, but displays the image inline, which disrupts the rest of the layout of the site

I'm by no means a Django expert, so there might be something easy I'm missing. I'm totally open to using other libraries to help if that's the best path forward, but am not sure of how to appropriately load them in to django admin. I'm also open to pure js/css solutions - whatever works best!

Here's the code that I have

```
def image_column(self, obj):
    format_html(foo + " " + \
            '''<a href="{}"" target="_blank" 
            style="font-size: 18pt" 
            onmouseover="document.getElementById('{}_img').style.display='block';"
            onmouseout="document.getElementById('{}_img').style.display='none';">  
            <img id="{}_img" style="display:none" src="{}" />'''.format(img_url, img_id, img_id, img_id, img_url)
```

I'd love any thoughts or suggestions on the best way to make it 'popover' instead of display inline. Thank you!!

EDIT:
Things are working now, with the exception of the camera emoji displaying over the pop over. The image in the background is a map (which should be on top). The camera image is from the row beneath it

[image: Camera emoji above pop over]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might only be an issue to do with the position property of the image, if it is `position: relative`, then it will fix itself among the other elements, you have to set it to `position: absolute` and from here you should give it `top` and `left`, for example: `top: 0px; left: 0px;` relative to the parent element which I guess is the `<a>` element ... And you should also apply `position: relative` to the parent element: which again I think is `<a>` or whichever parent element is to the `<img>` element

Comment: Thanks! I'll gladly give that a shot. My CSS (especially CSS as it's applied within weird python code snippets) is somewhat limited - what's the best/cleanest way to make those modifications to the code above?

Comment: Just add the respective styles within the `style` attributes: as you already have style attributes, for the `<a>` element add `position: relative` to this attribute: `style="font-size: 18pt; [add it here]"` and to the `<img>` element, add `position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px` to the respective style attribute ... for the "top" and "left" you can customize to your needs

Comment: Awesome, thank you - this almost does it. Right now, it makes it hover over the top left of the screen (which makes sense, given the coordinates). If possible, I'd love to make it hover by the mouse itself (near the <a> element). I tried switching the position of the <img> to relative, but that made it pop back in line and distort the overall layout. Is there anything else you'd suggest? Thanks again!

Comment: Based on what I know, first question, is the `<img>` tag wrapped around by the `<a>` element? If so, then setting the position to relative for the `a` element will fix that, **POINTER**: For an element to be positioned absolute but relative to any other element, the parent(Whatever element is enclosing that element) has to have `position: relative` or even absolute.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. I was able to fix it by doing exactly what you suggested - adding a position relative to the <a> element. Thank you!!

Comment: One final question - thank you so much for your help @Cypherjac. Right now, the image pops over all of the other content, except for the other camera icons in rows beneath it. Any ideas for how to make it pop over *everything*?

Comment: Is it possible to show an image? You can just edit it into your original question

Comment: No problem - just added! I tried wrapping the emoji in a <div> with style="z-index:-5; position:relative" but that didn't do the trick

Comment: I think I fixed my own problem - I had success adding z-index:1 to the image itself. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216231/discussion-between-mythander889-and-cypherjac).