# Django admin - make image appear over the django admin list view

Tags: javascript, css, django, django-admin

Following up on a question from [Django Admin - display image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434795/django-admin-display-image-on-hover/62435244#62435244). I'm able to make the image appear on hover like I was hoping. However, if the django admin list view only has a few items in it, part of the image appears behind the bottom of the list

Here's an example of what it looks like, with some column headers greyed out

[image: image underflow]

The image extends beneath the bottom of the list (as hinted at by the appearance of the scroll bar). We'd like it to pop over the top, so the full image is visible regardless of the length of the list

Here's the code we have

```
def image_column(self, object)
    return format_html(text+" "+\
                '''<a href="{}"" target="_blank" 
                style="font-size: 18pt; position: relative;" 
                onmouseover="document.getElementById('{}').style.display='block'; position: relative;"
                onmouseout="document.getElementById('{}').style.display='none';"><div style="position:relative"></div>  
                <img id="{}" style="display:none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width:550px; border:5px solid; z-index:1000;" src="{}" /> </a>'''.format(
                    url, img_id, img_id, img_id, url))
```

I've tried setting the `position:absolute` in the image tag to `position:relative`. This makes sure the whole image is displayed when you mouse over (expanding the containing row). However, it affects the the layout of the rest of the document, which is disorienting the user

Thank you!!!

Comment: Try setting this property to the whole list view element(the parent to the `<a>` elements): `overflow-y: visible;` ... This disables scrolling and makes it **visible**

Comment: Thanks Cypherjac! Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure how to get access to that - Django only allows me to inject code into the cell itself, but I'm not sure where to modify the parent css. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: I tried grabbing with `document.getElementById('{}').parentNode.parentNode.style.overflow-y=visible;`, but that only succeeded in crashing my backend

Comment: Ok, how about this, I assume the `HTML` equivalent for django `listview` is: `<ul>`, if that the case try this: `document.getElementsByTagName('a').closest('ul').style.overflowY = "visible" ;`

Comment: I added that as a second piece after the existing `onmouseoever` but got the following error: "document.getElementsByTagName(...).closest is not a function"

Comment: Probably the `closest()` function is not yet supported by all browsers, but other than that, try fixing your initial test to this: `document.getElementsByTagName('a').parentNode.parentNode.style.overflowY = "visible";` Note the `overflowY` is in **camelCase** ... this one: `overflow-y` implies a subtraction

Comment: Thanks for working through this with me. I added that in, but get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onmouseover (?q=:338)`

The current line looks like this `onmouseover="document.getElementById('{}').style.display='block'; document.getElementsByTagName('a').parentNode.parentNode.style.overflowY = 'visible';"`

Comment: Then I guess your `document.getElementById('{}')` should work here, replace `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` this with that one with the id, if an error occurs, try removing a `parentNode`(just for testing) and check the logs

Comment: Makes sense - that code runs without errors, but the image still underflows the bottom of the list. I tried removing/adding `parentNode` calls to make sure we weren't off by one, but didn't have any luck

Comment: This is definitely the styling that's affecting the element (Since you've stated it only happens when the list items are little), Here's a few more suggestions: Set the `height` of the `ul` to `max-content` ... in the same way the styles are being applied above with the parentNode

Comment: Can do. Right now, it's editing it such that the <tr> element is showing up like this:
`<tr class="row1" style="overflow-y: visible; height: max-content;">`. It looks like setting it is working correctly; is that the right level in the tree to set it at?

Comment: This is also due to the height of the image ... you can give the images a predefined height that will apply for all of them, as a last resort you can downsize the images in a way that they all appear without causing any scrolling ---------- OK I guess I was wrong about the listview being `<ul>`, but it seems it's applying to the correct element. since the child of that would be a `<td>`

Comment: I tried explicitly setting the height to 300px so that it's now `<img id="65a7fdb978e54d32_csimg" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 550px; height: 300px; border: 5px solid; z-index: 1000;" src="foo.jpg">` but didn't have any luck. I like the idea of downsizing the images, but unfortunately when they're that small they're unreadable

Comment: Ok, since the container is `<tr>` (that has been established) , you can set the container of the element to increase in size when the image is displayed -- probably the `300px` which is defined for the image [This could lie within the mouseover and mouseout event listeners] ... `onmouseover=" ... //other code ... document.getElementById("{}").parentNode.parentNode.style.height = "300px";` then unset it during the `mouseout` event

Comment: That did the trick! I also had to remove the `top: 0px; left: 0px;` setting - it created a weird effect where the image loading in would move the icon out from under the mouse, which would subsequently hide the image

Comment: Glad that issue is fixed

Comment: Same here! If you post a blurb as a solution I'm happy to accept it so you get credit for it

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, only reason was that I wasn't sure with my answers you know, it was all testing back and forth